# Collection.get returning undefined in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have issue with collection.get and model.get returning undefined.

here is my initializecode

```
initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new productsCollection();
    this.model = new productModel();
}
```

here is my render code

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function (product) {
        console.log(product);
        $(that.el).html(_.template(productListTemplate, { products: product.models, _: _ }));
    }
});
```

my list of products is displaying fine. when i click on each product i get a popup where name can be changed

i want to get the set new name in the model and trigger save

but i am unable to get the model of the product here is the code

```
$("#productName").val($(e.currentTarget).html());

var ID = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
var item = this.collection.get(ID);

console.log("start..........");
console.log(item);
console.log(ID)
//            console.log(this.collection);
console.log(this.model.get(item));
console.log("end..........");

$('.modal').modal('toggle');
```

I am able to get the correct id in console but not collections and models

can some one help thanks in advance

***UPDATE***
here is the complete view code

```
function ($, _, Backbone, popupModal, productTab, productsCollection, productListTemplate, productModel) {
    var productListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new productsCollection();
            this.model = new productModel();
            this.model.bind('change', this.loadResults, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.loadResults();
        },
        loadResults: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function (product) {
                    console.log(product);
                    $(that.el).html(_.template(productListTemplate, { products: product.models, _: _ }));
                }
            });
            var modalWindow = $(".modal").modal({
                show: false,
                backdrop: true,
                closeOnEscape: true
            });
            $('#createProduct').click(function (e) {
                this.modalWindow.modal('show');
            });
        },
        // This will simply listen for scroll events on the current el
        events: {
            "click #saveProduct": "saveProduct",
            "click .productTabs": "productTabs",
            "click .productDetails": "productDetails"
        },
        saveProduct: function () {
            this.model.set({
                Name: $('#productName').val()
            });
            this.model.save({ id: this.model.get('id') },
         {
             success: function (model, response) {
                 //                 console.log("success");
             },
             error: function (model, response) {
                 //                 console.log(response);
                 var errorMsg = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                 $(".errorMessage").html('<div class="alert alert-error">' + errorMsg.Error + '</div>');
             }
         });
        },
        productTabs: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        },
        productDetails: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#productName").val($(e.currentTarget).html());
            var ID = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
            var item = this.collection.get(ID);
            console.log("start..........");
            console.log(item);
            console.log(ID)
            //            console.log(this.collection);
            console.log(this.collection.models.get(item));
            console.log("end..........");
            $('.modal').modal('toggle');
        }
    });
    return new productListView;
});
```

**UPDATE** responses

*this.collection*

```
b.hasOwnProperty.e
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
_removeReference: function () { [native code] }
length: 2
models: Array[2]
0: b.hasOwnProperty.e
1: b.hasOwnProperty.e
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: s​
```

It has 2 models and my list also has 2 products

*this.model*

```
_callbacks: Object
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
ID: ""
Name: ""
hRef: ""
__proto__: Object
cid: "c2"
__proto__: s
```

The attributes are empty

*this* gives me following

```
cid: "view1"
collection: b.hasOwnProperty.e
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
_removeReference: function () { [native code] }
length: 2
models: Array[2]
__proto__: s
model: b.hasOwnProperty.e
_callbacks: Object
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
cid: "c2"
__proto__: s
options: Object
__proto__: s
```

**UPDATE** This is what i see when i expand my collections

```
b.hasOwnProperty.e
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
_removeReference: function () { [native code] }
length: 2
models: Array[2]
0: b.hasOwnProperty.e
_callbacks: Object
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
ID: "7e0c94fc-7c16-45c9-84a9-a0690103b946"
Name: "dsa"
hRef: "Product/dsa"
__proto__: Object
cid: "c3"
collection: b.hasOwnProperty.e
__proto__: s
1: b.hasOwnProperty.e
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: s
```

Comment: The code example here is very _dismembered_, we can't see how one portion collaborates with the other. Please provide a more consistent and completed example code.

Comment: @fguillen i have posted the whole code

Comment: What do you exactly see when you run the commented line `console.log(this.collection);`? also what do you see if you would run `console.log(this.model);`? .. even `console.log(this);`?

Comment: @fguillen I have updated the post not sure why the attributes are empty in my model.

Comment: Into the `this.collection` is there any of the `models` with the `id` equal to your `ID` variable? (you can browse it into your JS console), remember that by default Backbone is gonna look into `Model.id` attribute, not into `Model.ID` attribute.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an `ID` vs `id` issue as well. What JSON is used to build a single model? Does it have an `id` key or an `ID` key?

Comment: I have update the post. I am using ID every where and my json response also has ID in it here is a sample Json {"ID":"7e0c94fc-7c16-45c9-84a9-a0690103b946","Name":"dsa","hRef":"Product/dsa"}. I am kind of stuck I am not sure y my collection.get wont work

Comment: `Model.id` is associated by Backbone with `Model.get("id")`if you want this association to be made with `Model.get("ID")` try to use the [Model.idAttribute property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have to bind all function that will call by DOM event, to the instance of your view:

So add this line into your `initialize` method:

```
_.bindAll(this, "saveProduct", "productTabs", "productDetails")
```

Otherwise `this` in the function will be global `window` object instead of the instance of your view.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
Collection.findWhere({_id: ID}) // get the right answer
```

we could conclude that :

- to Model, the key is [**idAttribute**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute)
- to Collection, the key is [**modelId**](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-modelId)

---

For example :

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Model });

var Persons = new Col([{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Ken'
}, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mike'
}, {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'John'
}]);

console.log( Persons.get(1) ); // undefined
```

If indicate the **idAttribute** of M :

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({ idAttribute: '_id' });
...
console.log( Persons.get(1) ); // the model of Ken
```

---

On some occasions we don't need Model, such as :

```
var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend();

var Persons = new Col([{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Ken'
}, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mike'
}, {
    _id: 3,
    name: 'John'
}]);

console.log( Persons.get(2) ); // undefined
```

For Solving this, we just need to rewrite the original **modelId** method :

```
var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    modelId: function() {
        return '_id';
    }
});
...
console.log( Persons.get(2) ); // the model of Mike
```

---

---

P.S : More detail in [official docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-modelId).

---

P.S again: Old versions of BackboneJS do not support **modelId**